# Gaussian filter kernel different from Matlab Gaussian filter kernel

Tags: matlab, filter, computer-vision, gaussian

I am creating a Gaussian filter in Matlab. I have created the following code for creating the kernel.

```
function kernel = gaussian_filter(sigma)
    kernel_width = 3 * sigma - 1;
    [x, y] = meshgrid(-kernel_width/2:kernel_width/2, -kernel_width/2:kernel_width/2);
    normalized_constant = 1/(2 * pi * sigma * sigma);
    kernel = normalized_constant * exp(-(x.^2 + y.^2)/ (2 * sigma * sigma));
    K = mat2gray(kernel);
    imshow(K);
    title('Gaussian Kernel');
 end
```

And my output is:

```
gaussian_filter(3)

ans =

  Columns 1 through 7

    0.0030    0.0044    0.0058    0.0069    0.0073    0.0069    0.0058
    0.0044    0.0065    0.0086    0.0101    0.0107    0.0101    0.0086
    0.0058    0.0086    0.0113    0.0134    0.0142    0.0134    0.0113
    0.0069    0.0101    0.0134    0.0158    0.0167    0.0158    0.0134
    0.0073    0.0107    0.0142    0.0167    0.0177    0.0167    0.0142
    0.0069    0.0101    0.0134    0.0158    0.0167    0.0158    0.0134
    0.0058    0.0086    0.0113    0.0134    0.0142    0.0134    0.0113
    0.0044    0.0065    0.0086    0.0101    0.0107    0.0101    0.0086
    0.0030    0.0044    0.0058    0.0069    0.0073    0.0069    0.0058

  Columns 8 through 9

    0.0044    0.0030
    0.0065    0.0044
    0.0086    0.0058
    0.0101    0.0069
    0.0107    0.0073
    0.0101    0.0069
    0.0086    0.0058
    0.0065    0.0044
    0.0044    0.0030
```

But when I run the Matlab Gaussian filter, the result is slightly off my output.

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', 9, 3)

h =

  Columns 1 through 7

    0.0040    0.0059    0.0077    0.0091    0.0096    0.0091    0.0077
    0.0059    0.0086    0.0114    0.0135    0.0142    0.0135    0.0114
    0.0077    0.0114    0.0150    0.0178    0.0188    0.0178    0.0150
    0.0091    0.0135    0.0178    0.0210    0.0222    0.0210    0.0178
    0.0096    0.0142    0.0188    0.0222    0.0235    0.0222    0.0188
    0.0091    0.0135    0.0178    0.0210    0.0222    0.0210    0.0178
    0.0077    0.0114    0.0150    0.0178    0.0188    0.0178    0.0150
    0.0059    0.0086    0.0114    0.0135    0.0142    0.0135    0.0114
    0.0040    0.0059    0.0077    0.0091    0.0096    0.0091    0.0077

  Columns 8 through 9

    0.0059    0.0040
    0.0086    0.0059
    0.0114    0.0077
    0.0135    0.0091
    0.0142    0.0096
    0.0135    0.0091
    0.0114    0.0077
    0.0086    0.0059
    0.0059    0.0040
```

I am not missing any steps in the algorithm. I am trying to figure out why our results don't match.

Comment: Kern*e*l, not kernal...

Answer (score 0):

I forget to normalize kernel:

```
kernel = kernel/(sum(kernel(:)));
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html